# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ce": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO

Tags: android, sqlite

I am initializing my variables as follows:

```
String separator = "" ;
String insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO " + PhoneContactsTable.TABLE_PHONE_CONTACTS + " (" +
          PhoneContactsTable.KEY_NAME +"," +  PhoneContactsTable.KEY_PH_NO +"," 
          + PhoneContactsTable.KEY_SNID +","+ PhoneContactsTable.KEY_EMAIL +") VALUES " ;

StringBuilder insertQuery2 = new StringBuilder();
```

I am generating insertQuery2(stringbuilder)  as follows:

```
try
{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(returndResultForSNID);

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        snid = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("snid");
        insertQuery2.append(separator).append("('").append(contactNameArr.get(i).toString()).append("','").append(contactPhoneNumberArr.get(i).toString()).append("','")
        .append(snid).append("',").append("''").append(")");
        separator = "," ;
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println( "Could not parse malformed JSONArray: " + e.toString() );
}
```

I am creating the last String as insertQuery3 which is being inserted into database:

```
try
{
    String insertQuery3 = insertQuery1 + (insertQuery2.toString()).toString();
    phoneContactsDAO.open(false);
    phoneContactsDAO.addFullStringToDb(insertQuery3);
    phoneContactsDAO.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println( "Could not added into database: " + e.toString() );
}
```

My database query is as follows which seem fine:

```
public void addFullStringToDb(String insertQuery3) 
{
  database.execSQL(insertQuery3);   
}
```

**This code worked in 4phones. But is not working on a 5th device**

Comment: might be interesting to view the `insertQuery3` string prior to its use in the `execSQL()` call.

Comment: I cant put the  whole string because of limitation:
Here is the error Im getting
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ce": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contact_phone (contatct_name,contatct_phone_number,contatct_snid,contatct_email) VALUES ('*567#','+88*567#','',''),('01715-192558','+8801715192558','',''),('01715-192558','+8801715192558','',''),('A','+88*222#','',''),('A. Hamid B','+88188150291','',''),('A. Kader tamoria S east','+881715192390','',''),

Comment: it should look like `insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3);` seems like you have too many parenthesis around the values. just a thought.

Comment: I am not getting any clue regarding the error. It works in other phones but not in one phone.
I am just trytin to insert the row values without  
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();          
          values.put(PhoneContactsTable.KEY_NAME, temp._name);
          values.put(PhoneContactsTable.KEY_PH_NO, temp._phone_number);
          values.put(PhoneContactsTable.KEY_SNID, temp._snid);
          values.put(PhoneContactsTable.KEY_EMAIL, temp._email);
database.insert(PhoneContactsTable.TABLE_PHONE_CONTACTS, null, values);

Comment: oh, shouldn't you run `execSQL()` on each JSONObject? looks like you are trying to insert multiple rows in one call.

Comment: exactly !!! anyways thanks for your query